How to translate AMQPComponent XML bean to Java bean for Camel with Spring Boot 3
I have an old Camel 2 with the old Spring Framework 4 app. It has been working for many years. I am upgrading it to Spring Boot 3 and Camel 4.5.0.
It has an amqp XML bean.
<bean id="alarmq" class="org.apache.camel.component.amqp.AMQPComponent">
   <constructor-arg value="${amqPoolConnFty}"/>
</bean>

A Camel route in the app references that AMQP component using the bean id alarmq in the endpoint
from("alarmq:queue:alarm-dispensary")
 .id("alarmeater")
 .to("direct:blahblah")

1st question

Where is the Camel document that says you can use a bean id as component spec of the url of an endpoint?
what is the pattern of an endpoint with a bean ref

I would like the answer only for Java DSL. It is not helpful for me to know how to configure Camel in XML.
2nd question
I need to translate the AMQP XML bean to @Bean in Java configuration.
I am thinking the Java bean should look like this
@Bean("alarmq")
@Inject
AMQPComponent getAMQPComponent(JmsPooledConnectionFactory jmsPoolConnFty) {
    AMQPComponent amqp = new AMQPComponent(jmsPoolConnFty);
    amqp.setConcurrentConsumers(5);
    return amqp;

}

Will Camel recognize the @Bean name as it recognizes the XML bean id, so that I could use the bean name in the from endpoint, like the XML bean id is used?
If not, how shall the AMQP component Java @Bean be structured?
Answers should be applicable to Spring Boot 3 and Camel 4.5.0.

1. question
a) I can't find it in the documentation, but the endpoint url is basically just a string, which is then getting parsed and resolved. Before the endpoint component is being resolved by name, the resolver checks the bean registry for that name. If nothing is found, it tries to resolve to the actual camel component.
b) The pattern stays the same, like you're already using. It just replaces the camel component name. Here that means alarmq replaces amqp. The rest of the configuration stays the same like the component itself. So for reference here is the documentation for the amqp component: https://camel.apache.org/components/4.4.x/amqp-component.html.
So after the : you need to specify the type, which can be either queue or topic followed by another : and then the destinationName.
This means, with the line alarmq:queue:alarm-dispensary you're reading from the queue "alarm-dispensary".
2. question
I typically create a configuration file, which I then annotate with @Configuration where I put all the global configuration in:
...
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean(name = "alarmq")
    AMQPComponent getAMQPComponent(JmsPooledConnectionFactory jmsPoolConnFty) {
        AMQPComponent amqp = new AMQPComponent(jmsPoolConnFty);
        amqp.setConcurrentConsumers(5);
        return amqp;
    }
}

With the @Configuration annotation it will get picked up automatically and create and register the bean called alarmq.
